# Custom operator to simplify If-Let

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I would like to simplify the constant need to do

```
if let firstName = firstName {
     self.name = firstName
}
```

A possible custom, generic operator to do this would be

```
infix operator ?= {}
func ?= <T>(inout left: T, right: T?) {
    if let right = right {
        left = right
    }
}
```

to simplify the previous example to

```
self.name ?= firstName
```

This creates an issue where if **firstName**'s value is *nil*, then Swift will wrap the value in an optional.

```
var name: String? = "Bob"
var firstName: String? = nil

self.name ?= firstName

print(self.name) 
/* 
     prints "nil" since it is wrapping firstName in an optional when 
     passed in.     

     E.g. Optional<nil> gets unwrapped to nil in function and assigned
*/
```

Any possible fix to the custom operator? I attempted to limit the left-hand parameter to not be an optional but that is not possible with generic's type constraints.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem (as you've correctly identified) is that because the left hand side argument is of type `T`, when you pass an optional into it `T` will be inferred to be `Optional<Whatever>`. Because the right hand side argument is `T?` (and because types can be freely promoted to optionals), it will infer the type to be `Optional<Optional<Whatever>>`, leading to the confusing double wrapping you're observing.

The solution is to add an overload to deal with the situation when the left hand side argument is also an optional.

```
infix operator ?= {}
func ?= <T>(inout left: T, right: T?) {
    if let right = right {
        left = right
    }
}

// overload to deal with an optional left handed side
func ?= <T>(inout left: T?, right: T?) {
    if let right = right {
        left = right
    }
}
```

<sup>(Note that in Swift 3, `inout` should appear before the parameter type)</sup>

Now if you use this operator with an optional as the left handed argument, Swift will use the overloaded version instead of the original version, as it'll always favour the more type-specific signature. This means that the right hand side won't get wrapped in a double optional, as it's now of the exact same type as the left hand side argument.

```
var name: String? = "Bob"
var firstName: String? = nil

name ?= firstName

print(name) // prints: Optional("Bob")
```

Note that this is similar to what the `??` does, it has two definitions to deal with one side being optional, one side being non-optional & both sides being optional in order to avoid the generation of double wrapped optionals:

```
@warn_unused_result
public func ??<T>(optional: T?, @autoclosure defaultValue: () throws -> T) rethrows -> T

@warn_unused_result
public func ??<T>(optional: T?, @autoclosure defaultValue: () throws -> T?) rethrows -> T?
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a interesting way to reduce the overhead of `if let` by **Nil Coalescing Operator**

> The nil coalescing operator (a ?? b) unwraps an optional a if it
>   contains a value, or returns a default value b if a is nil. The
>   expression a is always of an optional type. The expression b must
>   match the type that is stored inside a.

In short - 
`nonOptional = optional ?? someDefaultValue`
E.g. -

```
let defaultColorName = "red"
var userDefinedColorName: String?   // optional variable

var colorNameToUse = userDefinedColorName ?? defaultColorName
```

So, here if `userDefinedColorName` is nil then `defaultColorName` will be get assighed to non-optional variable `colorNameToUse`.
For complete reference check this [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html)