# Swift: assign optional value into non-optional var

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any concise way built into the language to *attempt* to assign the contents of a Swift optional into a non-optional `var`, simply doing nothing if the optional contains `nil`?

Essentially I'm imagining something like optional chaining ("execute this method call on this optional only if the optional is non-`nil`") but for assignment, e.g.:

```
// Fictional code. Assigns into nonOptional if non-nil; does nothing if nil:
nonOptional =? mightBeNil

// Equivalent but less concise real code:
if let notNil = mightBeNil {
    nonOptional = notNil
}
```

Comment: [See this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37442593/custom-operator-to-simplify-if-let) for an example of that exact operator

Comment: Nice! Didn't find that when I was searching around before asking. Should I delete this question, or wait 'till someone marks it as a duplicate? (It could maybe make the other one more discoverable?) Either way not sure I have the rep to mark it as a duplicate myself.

Comment: I would wait for someone to come around with a dupe hammer to, as you correctly say, increase the visibility :)

Comment: Here, let me dupe that for you :D